# Для каких целей используется spacer?

Tags: html, css

Есть у меня тема адаптивное меню на сайте, которое на малых разрешениях сворачивается в кнопку-бутерброд. Хочу поинтересоваться: для чего может использоваться класс `spacer` расположенный сразу перед кнопкой, который при скроллировании вниз неприятно дергает эту самую кнопку?
наглядная демонстрация: [демо сайта](http://velikorodnov.com/wordpress/flatastic/classic/)

моя догадка: при включении функции залипания меню при скроле вниз он должен является своеобразным буфером, но почему-то этого не просиходит..?

```css
.spacer {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="menu_wrap clearfix t_xs_align_c" data-shrink="yes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mobile-button" id="mobile-button"></div>
    <nav id="navigation" class="navigation" style="display: none;">
      <div class="logo-sticky"></div>
      <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Новости</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="searchform-wrap">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="search-outer">
        <form method="get" id="searchform" action="#">
          <p>
            <label for="s">Искать на:</label>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Введите текст и нажмите ENTER" value="">
            <button type="submit" class="submit-search" id="searchsubmit">Поиск</button>
          </p>
        </form>
        <button class="close-search-form"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://webref.ru/html/spacer

Comment: @Visman случайно отправил недоредактированный вопрос. исправил

Comment: @Visman знаю - я об этом написал. но назначение аналогичное - заполнять пустое пространство, ибо название идентичное. вот я и интересуюсь - может быть кто на опыте подскажет зачем тут он применяется?

Comment: так вы же сами сказали: для пустого пространства. И с его помощью можно не только сверху пустое пространство организовать, но и сбоку.

Comment: смысл пустого пространства, когда изначально он в стилях равен нулю?.. хотя, я похоже стал догадываться - скорее всего он нужен при включении функции залипания верхнего меню при скролле вниз

Answer (score 1):

Просто пользовательский html-тег, стиль/поведение которого верстальщик определил через CSS. HTML5 позволяет это, хоть и не рекомендует.

Соответственно тег этот мог быть использован как угодно, в зависимости от мысли верстальщика.

Comment: я дополнил описание. Подскажите, моя догадка может быть верной?